# Categorical regression of all variables in an 2D numpy array using statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I want to have a function which takes two arguments - a vector y and a 2d matrix X (both are represented as numpy arrays and we can assume the length of y is the same as the number of rows in X), and then return regression summary of an OLS regression of y on X (treating each column as an independent **categorical** variable). And I want to use only numpy and statsmodels to achieve this.

For example, if I just want to regress y on X, it should be easily achieved as follows,

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

def f(y, X):
    return sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(X), missing="drop").fit()
```

But my question is how can I do the same regression (y on X) with similar code as above with the only difference of treating each column in X as **categorical** instead of continuous?

Thanks for your time and help!